# How do I post a job on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, posting

I'm having a hard time finding how to post a company job opportunity on the Stack Overflow website. Please advise.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to [Talk to an Expert](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent/talk-to-an-expert) page
2. Fill the form and click "Talk to an Expert" Button

Then, they will contact you.

Comment: they's discontinuing the SO jobs in 2 months (may 1st, 2022), I used the talk to an expert and never got contacted so I think they stopped accepting new ones already saddly.