# Rates for advertisements on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Could anybody please let me know the rates of posting a job advertisement for our company on the site? I've sent an email and completed an inquiry form but am not receiving a response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I post a job on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368142/how-do-i-post-a-job-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @Tomerikoo it clearly does not. Their post say they did that, but got no reply afterwards.

Comment: @Luuklag look below. Apparently it does...

Answer (score 1):

We appreciate you reaching out. I checked the system and it looks like someone emailed you to connect on March 24th. I'll ask the sales rep to email you again just in case.

Comment: JFC your username and profile (aside from bio) do not at all indicate you are SO staff, much less a director. You should address this.